# What advice would you give me?

Tags: quran, tafseer, islamic-philosophy, quran-translation

I want to know Islam inside out. I am new at this. Currently, I am reading Qur'an from the official website "Quran.com" in the chronological order being Surah-al-Alaq the first. And I am reading Tafseer Ibn Kathir from the same website with translation. What advice would you like you give me at this stage? Also, whose written biography should I read?

Also, learning Arabic from Duolingo.

Comment: There is no "official" website of Islam or Quran , but yeah, quran.com is a good website. You can't learn Islam "inside out" without spending years, or even decades learning all the sciences (Tafsir, hadith, fiqh, kalam, etc.). However, good to start would be a "sharh of aqeedah tahawiyyah" (Look the exact thing up, find the relevant result) which is the most fundamental of texts in creed. You can do any of what are called "Fard ayn" courses from popular sources that teach the basics of living life based on specific madhahib.

Comment: E..g, http://www.mccgp.org/fard-ayn-certificate-course.html (this one is for the Hanafi madhab).

Comment: Once you've gotten the hang of absolute fundamentals in aqeedah and fiqh, you can start reading seerah (Actually, you can read it before that as well really, no prerequisite for reading basic seerah text lol). The Sealed Nectar is a book I hear of frequently being easy for laymen.

Comment: Then if you are still serious of learning Islam properly, then enroll into an Islamic scholarship course at any popular sunni institute. I can't remember the names of organizations who have online courses, but you can look them up.

Comment: Also, Duolingo, to my knowledge is not very helpful. It doesn't teach you anything besides a few words from what I am told (never tried). I think you should do an actual Arabic course like the one by academy.seekersguidance or yaqeen institute

Comment: @SyedM.Sannan I see, Thank you.